# How to autoload Roslyn Analyzer (without codefix)

Tags: c#, roslyn, autoload, visual-studio-extensions, analyzer

**TL;DR**

- Created `VSIX Package`
- Added `Analyzer` project item
- Pressed F5.
- The experimental instance starts but the **analyzer is not loaded** and can't be debugged.
- Manually adding the analyzer works.
- **Question:** how to autoload the analyzer?

**Problem description:**

There are lots of tutorials (even official docs) that start with a project template: `Analyzer with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)`. However, in the latest version of .NET Compiler Platform, I don't have such project template.

So, I've created a `VSIX project`. Then, I have created a `Analyzer` project item. Note that I don't have a `CodeFix` item as I don't need to fix code, only show some warnings.

This is what I've got (I've made a few changes):

```
[DiagnosticAnalyzer(LanguageNames.CSharp)]
public class MyAnalyzer : DiagnosticAnalyzer
{
    public const string DiagnosticId = "MyAnalyzer";
    internal static readonly LocalizableString Title = "MyAnalyzer Title";
    internal static readonly LocalizableString MessageFormat = "MyAnalyzer";
    internal const string Category = "MyAnalyzer Category";

    internal static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, true);

    public override ImmutableArray<DiagnosticDescriptor> SupportedDiagnostics 
        => ImmutableArray.Create(Rule);

    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(Analyze, SyntaxKind.IfStatement);
    }           

    private void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        IfStatementSyntax ifStatement = context.Node as IfStatementSyntax;

        if(ifStatement == null)
            return;

        context.ReportDiagnostic(
            Diagnostic.Create(
                Rule, 
                context.Node.GetLocation(), 
                "Hey, this is an IF statement."));
        }

    }
}
```

That's it. The project contains only this file, a `.vsixmanifest` and a `packages.config`.

When I run the project in debug mode (with F5), the experimental instance is loaded and I can see the package in `Extensions and Updates`. However, no breakpoints are being hit (*no symbols loaded*) and the analyzer is not visible in the list of analyzers (in solution explorer).

Then I do the following:

- Rename .vsix file in output folder to .vsix.zip and open it
- Extract the assembly DLL from the zip
- Right-click analyzers in solution explorer
- Manually browse/add the analyzer's assembly DLL

Then all of a sudden, symbols are loaded and the debugger stops on breakpoints.

Is there any way to load analzyer automatically in the experimental instance? Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: The templates have recently been upgraded: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The VSIX template is available from the [Visual Studio gallery](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2ddb7240-5249-4c8c-969e-5d05823bcb89).

I suspect that what's missing from your vsix project is the correct list of components in the VSIX package manifest. You need to define both a `MefComponent` and an `Analyzer` in your list of assets:

[image]

Comment: When I try to install the extension from the above link, it says I already have it installed. However, I don't have such a project template ("Analyzer with CodeFix"). I'm gonna check this and provide feedback.

Comment: What is the .NET framework version you have selected in the new project Ui?

Comment: you are on the right track. I had 4.5.1 selected. When I switch to 4.5.2+ it shows the template. Thanks. Didn't know it was available only in 4.5.2 or later.

Comment: Anyways, I've added the assets as you suggested, and it worked correctly. Now I know how to make this from scratch too :) Thank you very much!